# PHP APC Cache Doesn't works 100%

Tags: php, store, fetch, apc

I found some problem.
When i running apc_store and more times update a page (refresh). APC stores previous value and do not stores updated value.

It's following code:

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) { apc_store('test', $i); echo apc_fetch('test'); } ?>
```

True output is:
1,2,3,4,5

But sometimes i have: 5,5,5,5,5

Why and how i can correct that bug?

Apc version is last: 3.1.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual: `apc_store`

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Check it, it could be that it fails to store. [Why would apc_store() return false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670034/why-would-apc-store-return-false)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are just too fast, thus you'll get the stale value from the previous execution. Remember, that this is a cache and not a kind of persistent global variable. The point is, that you usually save data into a single key only once during a request and you'll try to fetch it in any subsequent request, but not the current one.

It seems you are looking for variables.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but what alternative?

Comment: The variable is object tree (instances of classes). Objects is updating through ajax.