# PHP apc_store then apc_delete then apc_store returns a failure

Tags: php, apc

I'm new to php and using APC framework. I'm trying to write some unit tests for a class that uses APC, but I'm running in to some problems trying to delete and then set some key values again in APC. My problem can be boiled down to a small set of code not working the way I would expect:

```
$success = apc_store("helloWorld", 2, 0);  // true
$success1 = apc_delete("helloWorld");      // true
$success2 = apc_store("helloWorld", 3, 0); // false
```

In addition doing a fetch call on `"helloWorld"` will return `NULL`, and I get the warning:

> [apc-warning] Potential cache slam averted for key 'helloWorld'

In addition I have tried to add this to my php.ini file:

```
apc.enable_cli=ON
```

I have also tried to increase the memory limit from the default 32M to 64M by adding this to my php.ini file:

```
apc.shm_size = 64M
```

I found this related question on in [Why would apc_store() return false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670034/why-would-apc-store-return-false), but neither suggestion worked me me though.

How can I fix this so that the expected three `true`s are returned? Why are they not being returned?

Comment: Does it work if you use `apc_add` on the third line?

Comment: Replacing `$success2 = apc_store("helloWorld", 3, 0);` with `$success2 = apc_add("helloWorld", 3, 0);` still yields success2 being false.

Comment: Note also I am using APC version 3.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code works perfectly for me (true/true/true) in PHP 5.3.12 with apc 3.1.9, so maybe you should try a later version?